# three.js shadowCascade DirectionalLight

Tags: three.js, shadow-mapping

I'm trying to copy the shadowCascade functionality from http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets_md2_control.html to my project. I did this 1:1 however I only get a a little bit of shadowing at a certain angles and rotations, and often cut off. Further, enabling shadowCascade from start throws shader errors. I have to wait for some time until I can set shadowCascade = true.

I tried to find documentation, links or hints explaining how shadowCascade works and what all those parameters do, without success so far.

All in all I'm rather confused, I don't really understand what is happening and why. Thanks in advance for some clarification and help!

[Here's a screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/rbfq7uggd/)

Edit: [Here's a video of the effect](http://youtu.be/VFoRv92BQh4)

Comment: The errors I get when directly enabling shadowCascade is "array size must be a positive integer" for stuff like 136: varying vec4 vShadowCoord[ MAX_SHADOWS ]; 137: uniform mat4 shadowMatrix[ MAX_SHADOWS ]; or in another shader 
114: uniform sampler2D shadowMap[ MAX_SHADOWS ];
115: uniform vec2 shadowMapSize[ MAX_SHADOWS ];
116: uniform float shadowDarkness[ MAX_SHADOWS ];
117: uniform float shadowBias[ MAX_SHADOWS ];
118: varying vec4 vShadowCoord[ MAX_SHADOWS ];

Comment: These mean that maxShadows is 0. maxShadows is set by allocateShadows in three.js. max_shadows only increases if a DirectionalLight has no shadowCascade. That's why it remains 0. Why this works in other examples I don't know yet though.

Comment: Ok I solved some part. Removing shadowCameraVisible = true helped to get rid of the errors, and I instead switched on shadowMapDebug = true;

Comment: When I use shadowMapDebug = true on the three.js example nothing happens...

Comment: Somehow the shadow camera moves when I move my camera...

Comment: The `shadowCascade` code has not been a significant focus of development in more than a year. There may be problems. If you want to pursue this, and track down possible bugs, that would be great. Some issues may be due to your device and/or browser, however.

Comment: If Id' like to create shadows for a 3rd person character which should look similar to sunlight, would you recommend using a SpotLight like http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shadowmap_performance.html?

Comment: For that I would use a directional light with the character as the `target` and a tight shadow box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shadowCascade` code has not been a significant focus of development in more than a year. There may be problems. If you want to pursue this, and track down possible bugs, that would be great. Some issues may be due to your device and/or browser, however.

For now, I would suggest you use a directional light with the character as the `target` and a tight shadow box.

three.js r.66

Comment: Further, since I use 3rd person, I do not need to have a shadow map behind the camera. Therefore I adjust the DirectionalLight's position according to the player's position and rotation. Onto the player I mounted a reference point (an Object3D with, in my case, position (0,0,-19)). Then I position the light in the render/tick method accordingly: var p2 = new THREE.Vector3(0,45,0).applyMatrix4(sunlightReferencePoint.matrixWorld); light.position.set(p2.x + 20, p2.y + 50, p2.z);